# Define default keyword arguments only once in a class

Tags: python, oop, keyword-argument

I have a class like this, where the default keyword argument values are repeated for every method:

```
class Example:
    def method_1(kwarg_a=None, kwarg_b=None):
        # Do something with kwargs
        pass

    def method_2(kwarg_a=None, kwarg_b=None):
        # Do something with kwargs
        pass

    def method_3(kwarg_a=None, kwarg_b=None):
        # Do something with kwargs
        pass
```

It would be convenient to only have to define the list of keyword arguments once. I mean something like the following.

```
# Doesn't compile, just for illustration.
class Example:
    kwargs = {'kwarg_a': None, 'kwarg_b': None}

    def method_1(**kwargs):
        # Do something with kwargs
        pass

    def method_2(**kwargs):
        # Do something with kwargs
        pass

    def method_3(**kwargs):
        # Do something with kwargs
        pass
```

Unfortunately, the last example doesn't work, as `kwargs` would only be expanded if called directly. It doesn't expand default values.

Does Python have such a functionality? If not, is there something similar to achive the goal of having to define the list of default keyword arguments only once?

Comment: There's no _syntax_ for that, but you could use e.g. decorators to apply the same logic to a bunch of methods.

Comment: Are all these methods static  ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi my original example is a Flask Method View class, so I believe no, its not static, but my example looks like this. Sorry for being a bit imprecise.

Comment: Also I don't get the concept where you are saying that kwargs would only be expanded if called directly ?

Comment: Saving yourself a tiny bit of typing to make your method signatures much more unreadable seems like a bad tradeoff.

Comment: @chepner in this example i agree with you, but what if there were a lot of arguments and a lot of methods?

Comment: The problem with your attempt is that there is no relationship at all between `Example.kwargs` and the parameter name `kwargs`. Function signatures are a *syntactic* construct, not an expression to be evaluated.

Comment: @MoritzLoritz Then you have a different refactoring problem ahead of you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, but I don't recommend it. Saving yourself a small amount of typing when you *write* the code is not worth the difficulty in later *reading* the code that you introduce.

```
class Example:
    def method_1(kwarg_a, kwarg_b):
        # Do something with kwargs
        pass

    def method_2(kwarg_a, kwarg_b):
        # Do something with kwargs
        pass

    def method_3(kwarg_a, kwarg_b):
        # Do something with kwargs
        pass

    for m in [method_1, method_2, method_3]:
        m.__defaults__ = (None, None)
```

Default values for keyword-only parameters are stored separately in `__kwdefaults__` (which is a mapping of parameter names to values, rather than a simple tuple of values).

Note that you can patch the default argument values later, but you can't patch the parameter list itself, so you still have to specify the list of parameters when the function is defined. (Or if you can, it would make your code even more unreadable.) It's also possible that all of the above is specific to CPython, and may not work in other implementations.

---

@jonsharpe mentioned a decorator in a comment. A decorator could use the same approach:

```
def add_defaults(f):
    f.__defaults__ = (None, None)
    return f


class Example:
    @add_defaults
    def method_1(kwarg_a, kwarg_b):
        pass

    ...
```